# Negative + でください

Tags: grammar, particles, syntax

Please note this [post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38995/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84-conjugation) does not answer the question, it’s not a duplicate.

> 熱い時開けない**でください**

This is the warning messages on your car for engine coolant.
But why is it not

> 熱い時開けなくてください,

Since it should be てform + ください？

で is the てform of だ, so could I see this sentence as 熱い時開けない事でください, since it’s always a noun that comes before だ？

Besides, I’ve also seen 熱いとき開けないこと being used as well.

Another supporting evidence is instead of そんな事はありません, some people say そんな事はないです, which, I think I can interpret as そんな事はない事です, right?

Is it valid, in these two cases, to put こと after the verb and before the で/です?

Comment: ないです comes from the negative form of ある, which is ない; that is an い-adjective, so to get the polite form, you add です, just like 暑いです, 小さいです and so on. It's not a short version of ないことです.

Comment: Right. Thanks. What about the negative + でください？

Comment: @DavidX you might be interested in https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11473/is-ないで-a-te-form and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11357/the-uses-etymology-of-で . My theory is that てください form asks for some action. なくて doesn't have action slot, because it's an adjective. ないで on the other hand might imply that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なくて and ないで are both valid て-forms but they have different functions. When used to connect clauses, なくて indicates cause and ないで attendant circumstances.

> 弟がドアを開けなくて困った。
> I had a hard time because my brother didn’t open the door (for me).

> ドアを開けないで返事をした。
> I replied without opening the door.

The former is used when some action is actually not performed and that causes some consequences, whereas the latter describes a situation in which some action is kept unperformed while some other action is performed.

ないでください is used to ask someone to refrain from doing something. It’s like asking them to keep the action of the verb unperformed. (*) なくてください doesn’t make sense.

ないで is also used in ないでおく. Again (*) なくておく doesn’t make sense.

> 寒いので窓を開けないでおこう。
> Since it is cold, let’s keep the window closed (*lit.* unopened).

> cf. 暑いので窓を開けておこう。
> Since it is hot, let’s keep the window open.

Comment: Suggestion: ～ないでおく might be more directly expressed in translation as "keep [something] un`[VERBED]`".

Comment: Yep. ないで is a valid te-form for negative verbs on its own. Now I know to regard it as a single unit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you use 熱い時開けなくて, you mean: when it's hot, do not open it **and**

なくて = な（い） + く　（liaison) + て

while ないでください means: please do not

Comment: I don't think this explains the construction.  If the ～て form were purely for the meaning "and", then positive ～て下さい constructions make no sense.  The question remains: why is positive ～てください a request, but negative ～なくてください not a negative request?